# SQL Server multi LEFT JOIN for same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have big data and multiple `LEFT JOIN`s for same table as below query

I have view AB_AccCard  which contains columns  [YID]  and [YParentID]

what I want is to look for [YID] in  [AB_ProcessDetail] and get YParentID  from [AB_AccCard]  then save it as [YParent]

then get [YParentID] for new [YParent]  and save it as [YParent2]

then get [YParentID] for new [YParent2]  and save it as [YParent3]

..... want this for 5 level

```
SELECT
    YPartner = ISNULL(AP.AccName, AC.AccName),
    YPartner2 = ISNULL(AP2.AccName, ISNULL(AP.AccName, AC.AccName)),
    YPartner3 = ISNULL(AP3.AccName, ISNULL(AP2.AccName, ISNULL(AP.AccName, AC.AccName))),
    YPartner4 = ISNULL(AP4.AccName, ISNULL(AP3.AccName, ISNULL(AP2.AccName, ISNULL(AP.AccName, AC.AccName)))),
    YPartner5 = ISNULL(AP5.AccName, ISNULL(AP4.AccName, ISNULL(AP3.AccName, ISNULL(AP2.AccName, ISNULL(AP.AccName, AC.AccName)))))
FROM 
    dbo.[AB_ProcessDetail] A WITH(NOLOCK) 
LEFT JOIN 
    AB_AccCard AC WITH(NOLOCK) ON AC.YID = A.YAccCardId 
                               AND a.DataBaseName = ac.DataBaseName
LEFT JOIN  
    (SELECT YID, AccName, YParentID, AccType, DataBaseName 
     FROM dbo.AB_AccCard WITH(NOLOCK)) AP ON AP.YID = ac.YParentID   
                                          AND AP.DataBaseName = AC.DataBaseName
LEFT JOIN  
    (SELECT YID, AccName, YParentID, AccType, DataBaseName 
     FROM dbo.AB_AccCard WITH(NOLOCK)) AP2 ON AP2.YID = AP.YParentID  
                                           AND AP2.DataBaseName = AC.DataBaseName
LEFT JOIN  
    (SELECT YID, AccName, YParentID, AccType, DataBaseName 
     FROM dbo.AB_AccCard WITH(NOLOCK)) AP3 ON AP3.YID = AP2.YParentID 
                                           AND AP3.DataBaseName = AC.DataBaseName
LEFT JOIN  
    (SELECT YID, AccName, YParentID, AccType, DataBaseName 
     FROM dbo.AB_AccCard WITH(NOLOCK)) AP4 ON AP4.YID = AP3.YParentID 
                                           AND AP4.DataBaseName = AC.DataBaseName
LEFT JOIN  
    (SELECT YID, AccName, YParentID, AccType, DataBaseName 
     FROM dbo.AB_AccCard WITH(NOLOCK)) AP5 ON AP5.YID = AP4.YParentID 
                                           AND AP5.DataBaseName = AC.DataBaseName
```

It takes a long time to execute.

How can I make it go faster?

Comment: See [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: Check this: learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/tune-nonclustered-missing-index-suggestions

Comment: Normally the advice is to use a common table expression for hierarchical data, but this  gives rows with levels. 

Could you explain what you are trying to achieve? This will gives us a better chance to find a way.

Comment: Please try: A LEFT JOIN B ON C1 OR C2 OR ...

Comment: I have view AB_AccCard  which contains columns  [YID]  and [YParentID] 
what I want is to look for [YID] in  [AB_ProcessDetail] and get YParentID  from [AB_AccCard]  then save it as [YParent]  
then get [YParentID] for new [YParent]  and save it as [YParent2]
then get [YParentID] for new [YParent2]  and save it as [YParent3]
..... want this for 5 level

Comment: With the information you've given, there's really not much that can be done. You haven't said what is `long time` -- for some it's 10 seconds, for others 10 minutes or something else... You haven't mentioned row counts, indexing. query plan or anything really.

Comment: @James Z
its take about 130 second 
I can't use indexing because I get data from other databases and I haven't access to create indexes

Comment: Well. indexing is typically the way to improve the performance. If you don't have the access, you need to talk to someone who has

Answer (score 0):

I have used OUTER APPLY with FUNCTION

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnAB_GetPartnerID] (@YParentID varchar(25),@DataBaseName varchar(4) )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
( 
SELECT  E.CardType,E.Code,E.AccName,E.YID, E.AccType,E.YParentID,E.DataBaseName
FROM AB_AccCard  E WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE e.YID = @YParentID AND E.DataBaseName =@DataBaseName 
)
```

And the query is

```
SELECT 
YPartner = ISNULL(AP.AccName,AC.AccName),
YPartner2 = ISNULL(AP2.AccName,ISNULL(AP.AccName,AC.AccName)),
YPartner3 = ISNULL(AP3.AccName,ISNULL(AP2.AccName,ISNULL(AP.AccName,AC.AccName))),
YPartner4 = ISNULL(AP4.AccName,ISNULL(AP3.AccName,ISNULL(AP2.AccName,ISNULL(AP.AccName,AC.AccName)))),
YPartner5 = ISNULL(AP5.AccName,ISNULL(AP4.AccName,ISNULL(AP3.AccName,ISNULL(AP2.AccName,ISNULL(AP.AccName,AC.AccName)))))
FROM [AB_ProcessDetail] A WITH(NOLOCK)
OUTER APPLY  fnAB_GetPartnerID (A.YAccCardId  , A.DataBaseName  ) AC
OUTER APPLY  fnAB_GetPartnerID (ac.YParentID  ,ac.DataBaseName  ) AP
OUTER APPLY  fnAB_GetPartnerID (AP.YParentID  ,AP.DataBaseName  ) AP2
OUTER APPLY  fnAB_GetPartnerID (AP2.YParentID  ,AP2.DataBaseName  ) AP3
OUTER APPLY  fnAB_GetPartnerID (AP3.YParentID  ,AP3.DataBaseName  ) AP4
OUTER APPLY  fnAB_GetPartnerID (AP4.YParentID  ,AP4.DataBaseName  ) AP5
```

But I still wonder if there is a better way

Comment: I don't think this can make it faster -- but you should know when you test it. And if it doesn't... it really shouldn't be an answer, but just an edit to your question.

Comment: its been 2 second faster 
and the CPU time and memory consumption have decreased by half